# How to write Regex For this form plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

iam using this form Plugin which can also Accept regex for validation 
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/
Iam looking for Regex Validation where the User can enter the value between 1 and 250 .
it cannot accept "0" also .The following should not be allowed no speacial characters and as well as no negative number such as -1 -2 -3 and so on 
this is the  form which it can accept   `"/^[1-9][0-9]?$/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking if a value is in a given range is not a typical scenario for the use of regular expressions. You could do that, but the plugin also seems to support custom validation functions which i would prefer in this case, because they are easier to read and understand. A custom function for your validation task would look like this:

```
function validate(){
  var value = parseInt($("#fieldId").val());
  return value > 0 && value <= 250
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|250)$
```